# CSS hover underline disappears in mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a button that gets underlined on hover. It works fine on desktop, but the underline is never visible when on mobile. What can I do to fix it?

[Codepen of button working correctly](https://codepen.io/vivchc/pen/bGQGyJB/c728a2d8f130fbaa8976885ebc6b3fde)

[Gif of how underline disappears on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGUNP.gif)

Interestingly if you view the codepen in mobile mode, the underline also disappears.

html

```
<button id="google" class="button" onclick="window.location.href='https://www.google.com/;">
  <span id="github" class="hover-underline-animation">Google</span>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 46 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="arrow-horizontal">
    <path fill="currentColor" transform="translate(30)" d="M8,0,6.545,1.455l5.506,5.506H-30V9.039H12.052L6.545,14.545,8,16l8-8Z" data-name="Path 10" id="Path_10"></path>
  </svg>
</button>
```

css

```
.button {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    margin-top: 9.5vh;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Button text */
.button span {
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    font-size: 1.1vw;
    font-weight: 500;
    /* Padding at end of button text */
    padding-right: 0.8vw;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Button arrow */
.button svg {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
/*     transform: translateX(-0.6em);
    transition: all 0.3s ease; */
}

.button:hover svg {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.button:active svg {
    transform: scale(0.9);
}

/* Underline animation on hover */
.hover-underline-animation {
    position: relative;
    /* Padding from button text */
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.hover-underline-animation:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 85%;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    /* Thickness of underline */
    height: 0.15em;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
    background-color: black;
}

.button:hover .hover-underline-animation:after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

I tried playing around with the CSS. If I change scaleX from 0 to 1 in .hover-underline-animation:after, it becomes visible. So I know the underline does exist. But the hover just doesn't play in mobile.

Comment: There is no "hover" in mobile. Historically, digitizers could not differentiate between a person's finger touching the device's screen and hovering over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no "hover" in mobile. Historically, digitizers could not
> differentiate between a person's finger touching the device's screen
> and hovering over it.  – [Heretic Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey)